# Why use exdend and implement at same time

Tags: java, generic-programming

Bellow is a class for Binary search tree.

```
class BinarySearchTree <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Node<T> root;
    public void add(T data) {
        Node<T> p = new Node<T>(data);
        if (root == null) {
            root = p;
        } else {
            root.addNode(p);
        }
   }
```

Why is the Comparable extended instead of implemented?
for example

```
class BinarySearchTree <T> implements Iterable<T>, Comperable <T>
```

Comment: In generic type bounds, you use `extends` both both classes and interfaces.

Comment: @Eran so I see that T has to extend Comparable and whole class has to implement methods of Iterable. Is that right?